# I added a button and for some reason media queries not working for it

Tags: html, css, media-queries

For some reason the media queries not applying, it works fine for any other class, i only had issue with this one

I tried, removing only, screen ect. none of the worked

```js
const showImageButton = document.getElementById("show-image-button");
const myImage = document.getElementById("my-image");
showImageButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  myImage.hidden = !myImage.hidden;
});
```

```css
button2,
input[type=submit] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button2,
input,
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

button2 {
  color: currentColor;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0
}

button2 {
  border-style: outset;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: .85em;
  width: 100%;
}

So i want to make it to be width 100% on mobile @media only screen {
  .button2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button2 id="show-image-button">Méret Táblázat</button2>
<img id="my-image" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2999/5106/files/True-to-Sole-nike-sneaker-sizechart_760x760.jpg?v=1611582903" hidden>
```

Comment: Is <button2> a custome tag?

Comment: Unless button2 is a custom tag, rename the html tag to just button. And in your CSS refer to it via #show-image-button instead

Comment: Yes it's a custom tag

Comment: every other style working properly, just the @media not

Answer (score 2):

`.button2` - having a dot means you are looking for an element which has class button2. But in your HTML structure I don't see a class with that name.

Try the below code , this looks for an element with the id *show-image-button*

```
@media only screen {
  #show-image-button {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding a class to it but nothing changed, i tried this code what you sent but still not working, thanks for the help tho

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the size of your screen. Try:

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px){
#show-image-button {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```